# Difference between implicit and explicit return from single-expression Closure in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift-playground

I encountered strange problem with Swift compiler.

This code failed to compile:

```
let str = "012345,abc,officer"
let components = split(str, { return $0 == "," })
//               ^ error: 'NSString' is not a subtype of 'String'
```

while this (without `return`) compiles and works as expected:

```
let components = split(str, { $0 == "," })
// -> ["012345", "abc", "officer"]
```

I don't understand why the first one failed. With my understanding from [the doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-XID_158), `{ expression }` is just a syntax sugar of `{ return expression }`.

**Is this a kind of bug, or am I missing something?**

If I make own func like `split`, it works regardless of `return`.

```
func mySplit(seq: String, isSeparator: ((Character) -> BooleanType)) -> [String]{
    var ret:[String] = []

    var startIdx = seq.startIndex;
    for var idx = seq.startIndex; idx < seq.endIndex; idx = idx.successor() {
        if isSeparator(seq[idx]) {
            ret.append(seq[startIdx ..< idx])
            startIdx = idx.successor()
        }
    }
    if(startIdx <= seq.endIndex) {
        ret.append(seq[startIdx ..< seq.endIndex])
    }

    return ret;
}

let result1 = mySplit(str, { $0 == "," })
let result2 = mySplit(str, { return $0 == "," })
```

---

edit: I found all of these work.

```
split(str, { (chr:Character) -> Bool in return chr == "," })
split(str, { (chr:Character) -> Bool in chr == "," })
split(str, { chr -> Bool in return chr == "," })
split(str, { chr -> Bool in chr == "," })
split(str, { (chr:Character) in chr == "," })
split(str, { chr in chr == "," })
split(str, { $0 == "," })
```

but these fail:

```
split(str, { (chr:Character) in return chr == "," })
split(str, { chr in return chr == "," })
split(str, { return $0 == "," })
```

---

edit2:

Making `mySplit` like this reproduces the problem.

```
func mySplit<R:BooleanType>(seq: String, isSeparator:(Character) -> R) -> [String] {
```

Comment: My *guess* is that the explicit untyped return is causing the compiler to try to resolve the types *within* the block, where it has less information and so fails.  I can't think of *why* that happens, though.

Comment: @sapi Thanks. It seems, explicit return needs explicit return type *at least* for built-in `split` function. The question will be, what makes built-in `split` differ from `mySplit`.

Comment: @sapi It seems, you are right. Using generics for the closure return type did the thing. It makes sense to me :) Thanks again.